# Enable Text Compression for a URL without file extension .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, magento2

I am trying to solve the "**Enable Text Compression**" opportunity on the new Lighthouse page speed audits and am wondering how to enable **text compression** for a **url** like below:

```
www.magento2.com/customer/section/load?sections=&update_sectionid=false&_=12345678
```

I'm hoping there is a way to do this with `.htaccess` however there is no `.txt` appended so am unsure how I can apply to this controller that is generating a **JSON** response.

I've tried adding to my gzip configuration:

```
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/json.*
```

However above does not seem to work.

I have also tried adding below to my `VHOST` in order to try and force the type:

```
<Location "/customer/section">
  ForceType application/json
</Location>
```

This however is not seeming to kick the compression into action. The response headers do show `content-type: application/json` so feel that Gzip should recognise this as a type of response that should be compressed.

My current gzip compression is set as below within `.htaccess`:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/json.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Where i have tried to enable by type however would like some other ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166734/magento-2-how-to-do-gzip-compression-and-minify-js-css-files-for-optimization

Comment: Thanks, yeah i did it in end with mod deflate which just worked out of the box. Thanks for the reply however.

Answer (score 1):

Using **mod deflate** instead with below config just worked for me in the end:

```
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddType x-font/otf .otf
    AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
    AddType x-font/eot .eot
    AddType x-font/woff .woff
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/png .png
   </IfModule>
```